# yfinance how to get data if the ticker is same for different exchanges

Tags: python, yfinance

I want to get historical price data using python and yfinance for Indonesian stocks. I see that there are many stocks that have the same name across different countries, for example AUTO (can be Indonesian company Astra Otoparts Tbk PT or NASDAQ's Autoweb Inc)

When I do `yf.download('AUTO')`, it's returning me a price data of Autoweb Inc, instead of Indonesian stock Astra Otoparts Tbk PT.

How can we select which exchange we want the ticker from?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only looked up the brand name in your question, AUTO.JK is the brand name. I have not checked if it is a rule to add abbreviated names.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AUTO.JK", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-03-01")

data.head()
    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2021-01-04  1115.0  1140.0  1100.0  1120.0  1093.855225     1639000
2021-01-05  1120.0  1150.0  1120.0  1130.0  1103.621826     1337200
2021-01-06  1140.0  1150.0  1090.0  1135.0  1108.505127     1507500
2021-01-07  1135.0  1145.0  1110.0  1115.0  1088.971924     2225300
2021-01-08  1115.0  1145.0  1115.0  1135.0  1108.505127     2546400
```

Comment: Oh thank you! JK means Jakarta which is Jakarta Stock Exchange, our central exchange. Then I must add the ".JK" to all of the stock tickers to be able to get from yfinance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Accepted as answer thanks!